# Adding data to map without overwriting - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple maps inside maps, such as:

```
Program = {'day0': {'area0': {'exercise0': 'value'}}, 'day1': {'area0': {'exercise0': 'value'}}};
```

And, I want to add data to 'exercise0'. But, sometimes previous data will not be set. Such as creating 'area0' without setting 'day1'.
So...

```
Program['day0']['area0']['exercise0'] = 'failure';
```

...this code doesn't work, because 'area0' is not set.

I have used addAll too:

```
Program.addAll({
  'day${dayIndex}': {
    "area0": {
      'area': Chest,
      'exercise0': {'exercise': Chest.exercises[0]},
    },
    "area1": {
      'area': FrontArm,
      'exercise0': {'exercise': FrontArm.exercises[0]},
    }
  },
});
```

But rn this one overwrites the existing values.

Comment: its very simple check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908405/how-to-add-a-new-pair-to-map-in-dart

Comment: `((Program['day0'] ??= {})['area0'] ??= {})['exercise0'] = 'failure';`